# Http Connection issues to EC2 Instance even after opening ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having trouble to do http connections to EC2 instance, even the inbound ports are open for 80 and 443 for all the traffic, 0.0.0.0/0.

Still not able to http connect to the host-

Tried telnet hostname 80, and
tried from the browser, Got : Connection refused error all the time.

Comment: Is the connection opened for both inbound and outbound? What server software are you using?

Comment: I am using AWS AMI  EC2 image, both in bound and outbound ports are open.

Comment: Is it a Linux AMI?

Comment: Yes, it is  Amazon Linux AMI

Comment: Can you show your security group settings, and how are you connecting (DNS or IP) and are you connecting from inside Aws or outside. Is your instance in a VPC, which subnet?

Comment: `Connection refused` would be unrelated to security groups, subnetting, etc.  `netstat -a -n -t` should reveal that you have no service listening on `0.0.0.0:80` or `0.0.0.0:443`.  Listening on 127.0.0.1 is a common mistake, and will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the inbound and outbound connections are open for port 80 and if required for SSL, then for 443 as well.

If the above step is already done, then connect to the server via the terminal and install apache or any server software.

```
1)  sudo yum update -y
2)  sudo yum install -y httpd24 
3)  If installed succesfully, then run this: sudo service httpd start
```

Now, try to connect to the server and if the config is fine, then a test Linux Page will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the instance resolved the issue.